# ssh command fails when run with ssh-dss as hostKeyAlgortihm

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, ssh-keys

I am running two commands one after other.

I run in the following sequence second command fails with error code 255

First Command:

```
ssh -ladmin -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no \
  -oUserKnownHostsFile=/tmp/known_hosts.sshHostKey \
  -oHostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-rsa 172.23.13.35 echo AN_INTERESTING_STRING'
```

Second Command:

```
ssh -ladmin -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no \
  -oUserKnownHostsFile=/tmp/known_hosts.sshHostKey \
  -oHostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-dss 172.23.13.35 echo AN_INTERESTING_STRING'
```

Just HostKeyAlgorithms are changed in both commands from ssh-rsa to ssh-dss.

But, If I reverse  the sequence of running these commands ( with ssh-dss as HostKeyAlgorithm first, then with ssh-rsa ). It all works fine.

This is only happening with me once I upgraded my openssh-clients version to openssh-clients-6.6.1 .
It was not happening my earlier version, which was openssh-clients-5.5 .

Does anyone knows the reason for all this?
Why both the sequence of running the command was not important in the previous versions ?
Why only seq1 works fine with new version ?
I am very much a newbie and do not know much about these keys. Kindly help.

Comment: in the first command you use ssh-rsa, is that a typo?

Comment: it's ssh-rsa only, corrected in other places. Sorry :(

Comment: Tried with 6.2, can't reproduce and can't find anything quickly scanning the changelogs.